# Visual Studio 2019 Offline Layout Update ignoring '--noUpdateInstaller'

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2019

We use a [“Visual Studio Offline Layout”](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) to deploy VS 16.6 to both developers and buildservers with mixed internet connections (offline / proxy / direct). Up until lately, the [installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-an-offline-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)/[update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) from previous VS instances (16.3 to be exact) worked quite well.

Currently, we cannot use the offline layout to install the local cached version of Visual Studio any more, because computers connected to the internet want to update “Visual Studio Installer” prior to installing anything.

The call to `vs_Professional.exe update --wait --norestart --noweb --noUpdateInstaller ...` fails with exit code '1' pretty quick after it was invoked.
Looking at the `dd_` logs in TEMP, we find:

```
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:08.06.2020 10:17:49: Starting VS setup process 'vs_installer.exe' with arguments ' --layoutPath "<unc_path>\vs2019_250520_layout" --in "\<unc_path>\vs2019_250520_layout\Response.json" update --passive --norestart --productkey ;-) --nocache --noUpdateInstaller --noWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.MFC --includeOptional --includeRecommended --addProductLang en-us --locale de-DE --activityId "2e4fbc9e-37da-4791-9228-11b9649b69fa" --pipe "d549be32-ee39-49d5-b871-bed44625cafb"'.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:08.06.2020 10:17:49: VS setup process C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vs_installer.exe started. All done.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:08.06.2020 10:17:49: Waiting for setup process to complete...
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:08.06.2020 10:17:54: Pipe disconnected.
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:08.06.2020 10:17:56: VS setup process exited with code 1
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:08.06.2020 10:17:56: Bootstrapper failed with client process error or unknown error.
```

We’re already using the [`--noweb` and `--noUpdateInstaller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) flags when calling the Visual Studio Installer, **which leads me to the assumption that those parameters are not handled correctly.**

Is there a way to actually force [`--noUpdateInstaller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), can the Visual Installer also be updated offline prior to updating Visual Studio?

---

edit: a possible workaround to this problem may be to determine if the target workstation is connected to the internet or not - and specify use '--noUpdateInstaller' based on the result of this check.

i.e. in our deployment script:

```
$hasInternetConnection = try {
  $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create( "http://microsoft.com" )
  $response = $request.GetResponse()
  $response.StatusCode -eq 200
}
catch {
  $false
}

# use '--noUpdateInstaller' iff we are not connected to the internet!
$updateInstaller = if ($hasInternetConnection) {
  ""
}
else {
  "--noUpdateInstaller"
}

$packageArgs = @{
  packageName    = $packageName
  fileType       = 'EXE'
  file           = $(Join-Path $layoutPath "vs_Professional.exe")
  softwareName   = 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Professional'

  silentArgs     = "$setupPrefix --passive --norestart --wait --productkey $productKey --nocache $updateInstaller --noWeb $selectedWorkloads --includeOptional --includeRecommended --addProductLang en-us"
  validExitCodes = @(0, 3010)
}

Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage @packageArgs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the `--noUpdateInstaller` switch is very misleading and doesn't quite do what it suggests by name.

The Visual Studio 'offline installer' will only really work offline if your computer has no connection to the internet, otherwise it will always reach out to MSFT and check whether updates are available or not, at least for the installer program `vs_installer.exe` itself. If you don't have a connection to the internet, you'll need to specify `--noUpdateInstaller` to ignore the error that it couldn't check for an update.

The "Tip" on [create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) says

> If you want to install from an offline source on a non-internet
> connected computer, specify both the --noWeb and --noUpdateInstaller
> options. The former prevents downloading updated workloads,
> components, and so on. The latter prevents the installer from
> self-updating from the web.

**what's missing there is that the command execution will actually fail if a newer version of the installer is available with exit code '1'.**
This seems to be broken by design, but can be worked around with a small modifications to your install/deployment/upgrade scripts.

---

### workaround #1 - always try to upgrade vs_installer first, then use the offline layout

(sample PowerShell script used to deploy VS to hosts, note: vs_professional.exe is called from UNC share!)

```
# let the magical vs_installer be updated, if vs has already be installed previously

if (Test-IsVSAlreadyInstalled) {
  try {
    vs_professional.exe --quiet --update --wait
  } catch {
    Write-Host "failed to update magical vs_installer"
  }
}

# only pass "update" if VS is already installed
$updatePrefix = if (Test-IsVSAlreadyInstalled) { "update" } else { "" }

# install or upgrade visual studio
vs_professional.exe $updatePrefix --passive --norestart --wait --productkey $productKey --noWeb $selectedWorkloads
```

---

### workaround #2 - only pass `--noUpdateInstaller` if not connected to the internet

NOTE: this will allow vs_installer.exe to update itself, yet only use vsix packages and binaries from your offline layout location.

(sample PowerShell script used to deploy VS to hosts, note: vs_professional.exe is called from UNC share!)

```
hasInternetConnection = try {
  $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create( "http://microsoft.com" )
  $response = $request.GetResponse()
  $response.StatusCode -eq 200
}
catch {
  $false
}

# use '--noUpdateInstaller' iff we are not connected to the internet!
$updateInstaller = if ($hasInternetConnection) {
  ""
}
else {
  "--noUpdateInstaller"
}

# only pass "update" if VS is already installed
$updatePrefix = if (Test-IsVSAlreadyInstalled) { "update" } else { "" }

# install or upgrade visual studio
vs_professional.exe $updatePrefix --passive --norestart --wait --productkey $productKey --nocache $updateInstaller --noWeb $selectedWorkloads
```

---

I'm using a script such as described in workaround #2 wrapped in a Chocolatey Package and getting good results so far.

Answer (score -2):

> The call to vs_Professional.exe update --wait --norestart --noweb
>   --noUpdateInstaller ... fails with exit code '1' pretty quick after it was invoked.

**Actually**, every time you update vs, you must first update the **vs_installer** program. And as you described, you use `vs_Professional.exe update --wait --norestart --noweb --noUpdateInstaller`, it means that you are updating the **vs_installer** program. [Hint from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/update-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019#deploy-an-update-to-client-machines).

> Is there a way to actually force --noUpdateInstaller, can the Visual
>   Installer also be updated offline prior to updating Visual Studio?

And `--noUpdateInstaller` means that it will prevent updating **vs_installer.exe**. If you execute update, it will return a non-zero exit code.  So you cannot use `--noUpdateInstaller` with update.

**1)** If you want to install the old VS offline package on your agent, you should use this command to install it:(disconnect the Internet)

```
C:\Layout\vs_Professional.exe --wait --norestart --noweb --quiet --noUpdateInstaller
```

**2)** If you want to update the vs offline package to the latest version, you should try this:

**On the server**, Find the program that previously created the offline installation package and update it with this command:

```
vs_Professional.exe --quiet --update
```

Then run this to overwrite the old Layout folder:

```
vs_Professional.exe --layout c:\xxx(the previous offline packages and overwrite the latest updates to this package)
```

**Or** run the second command directly will also update the offline package to the latest version.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: actually I want to update an existing client OR install to a new client. the command I provided works fine if no update to vs_isntaller is available, but fails as soon as a new version of vs_installer can be found online. - works always for hosts that do not have internet connection (both upgrade and initial install scenario.)

Comment: the resource you provided states the following:

First, update the Visual Studio installer:
vs_enterprise.exe --quiet --update

Then, update the Visual Studio application itself:
vs_enterprise.exe update --installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise" --quiet --wait --norestart

so actually 'vs_enterprise update' seems to be the correct command to upgrade VS (which indeed works the way I expect it to according to this documentation)

Comment: Since you have a workaround about your issue, I suggest you could add an answer and then mark your answer so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues.

Comment: I am behind corp proxy. This worked for me (after moving install to short path d:\vs\): `vs_enterprise.exe --quiet --update` and then `vs_enterprise.exe update --installPath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise" --quiet --wait --norestart --noweb --force`