# Cannot perform offline network install of VS2019 on offline PC even following suggested steps

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Following the advice from MS ([Create, maintain, and deploy a network installation of Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)) I created a local layout cache on a network drive, from a PC with internet access:

> vs_Professional.exe --layout r:\layout --lang en-US --useLatestInstaller --add...

I'm using the latest version, at this time that's 16.11.

On another PC which can access the network drive but has no internet access, I ran:

> r:\layout\vs_Professional.exe --noWeb --noUpdateInstaller

The installer launches as expected and lets me select the components/workflows, and begin to install. After a couple minutes sitting on "0 B downloaded" I get these popups:

[image]

In the logs I see the specific packages are mentioned:

> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Branding.Professional,version=16.11.31605.320,language=en-US' failed to download from 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/45dfa82b-c1f8-4c27-a5a0-1fa7a864ae21/b93292eddeee33ce27e3475a520e5c1ce6168513700793500fff30c7e0ee3ed4/payload.vsix'.

> Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Resources,version=16.11.32002.261,language=en-US' failed to download from 'https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/b763973d-da6e-4025-834d-d8bc48e7d37f/2a207839625be3f15d38045676f1ebc59d376548f01abe553188d23ecdd926da/payload.vsix'.

Looking in my *layout* I can confirm the exact same versions *are* there:
[image]

I have *already* looked around quite a bit and seen similar reports:

- [Visual Studio 2019 Offline Layout Update ignoring '--noUpdateInstaller'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259223/visual-studio-2019-offline-layout-update-ignoring-noupdateinstaller)
- [Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise Offline Installation Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42685569/visual-studio-2017-enterprise-offline-installation-fails)
- and this long discussion with MS where they claim a fix was made in an earlier version: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cant-install-vs-2019-while-running-with-noweb-swit/582953

I have tried installing some certificates as per MS instruction:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-certificates-for-visual-studio-offline?view=vs-2019

I don't know what else to try. It's clearly trying to download from the internet but as far as I can see I've done everything I'm supposed to to make this work. I don't *think* the installer is trying to update, it's core VS2019 components right?

What have I missed?

I provide my `response.json` in case it sheds any light. I have already run `--verify` on my layout without any reported issues:

> { "installChannelUri":".\ChannelManifest.json",
> "channelUri":"https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/channel",
> "installCatalogUri":".\Catalog.json",
> "channelId":"VisualStudio.16.Release",
> "productId":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional", "add":[
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktop;includeRecommended",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop;includeRecommended",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreTools;includeRecommended",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Node;includeRecommended",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python;includeRecommended",
> "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal;includeRecommended"],
> "addProductLang":["en-US"], "useLatestInstaller":true}